# Ransack:Error - I'm trying to render nav bar with ransack search bar on every page but getting errors when I click on show, new page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I'm new to ruby on rails and I'm trying to build reddit clone. I'm trying to render nav bar with ransack search bar on **every page** and it works fine for the index page; but I'm getting errors when I click on any other page, because search_form_for is expecting data. I want users to see search bar on every page, but "searching" to be optional, so users can still move from page to page. English is my second language and I hope this makes sense.

In _main_nav.html.erb:

```
 <%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :title_cont %>
    <%= f.search_field :title_cont %>

    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
```

In subs_controller.rb:

```
 def index 
    @q = Sub.ransack(params[:q])
    @subs = @q.result
 end
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add a condition where you check if the parameter is present:

```
def index 
  @subs = if params[:q].present?
    @q = Sub.ransack(params[:q])
    @q.result
  else
    Sub.all
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much!